# Sensenet length filter Not working

Tags: rest, odata, sensenet

I want to query the Field which are empty and which are not empty using Sensenet Odata Rest API. Their documentation mentions a filter function called 'length'. I have tried to query the field with the length operation but it fails with the error.

This is the filter I have used

```
$filter=length(Name) eq 2
```

Sense/Net 6.5.4.9496

Exception

```
"code": "NotSpecified",
"exceptiontype": "SnNotSupportedException",
"message": {
"lang": "en-us",
"value": "Unknown method: length"
},
```

Wiki Link http://wiki.sensenet.com/OData_REST_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *length* operation was included in the list of supported methods incorrectly, we apologise for that. SenseNet compiles these filters to *Lucene* queries and it is not possible to compose such a query in Lucene that *performs an operation* on a field.

(the remaining methods, like *substringof* or *startswith* can be compiled to a wildcard expression easily, so that should work)

Unfortunately 'empty' expressions are also not supported by Lucene, because of their document/term structure. So the following expression does not work either:

```
Description eq ''
```

**Edit**: as a workaround, developers may create a custom *field index handler*.

For every field you want to check for emptiness (e.g. *Description*), you may create a technical hidden bool field (*IsDescriptionEmpty*) in the content type definition. The only thing you have to create and define is a custom field index handler class. In your case it would inherit from the built-in *bool field index handler* and you could return a boolean index value based on whether the target field (in this case Description) is empty or not.

After this you would be able to define search exressions like the following:

```
+Type:File +IsDescriptionEmpty:true
```

Please check the wiki article below and the source code for index handler examples.

[How to create a field indexhandler](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_create_a_FieldIndexHandler)

Comment: Is there any other way to Know that the Field is Empty or not empty in sensenet?

Comment: Hi, I added a workaround for developers to the answer above: creating a custom field index handler.